# unable to call setAttribute inside function

Tags: angular, typescript, function, dom-events

I'm getting an error when trying to call setAttribute() inside of toggleDiv(). Basically my IDE does not recognize the function and throws an error. How do I get it to recognize the function. This is an Angular project.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cocktails',
  templateUrl: './cocktails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cocktails.component.css']
})
export class CocktailsComponent implements OnInit {
  apiData = 'https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v2/my_key/popular.php';
  cocktailList: any;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getApiData().subscribe((cocktails) => {
      this.cocktailList = cocktails.drinks;
      console.log(cocktails);
    });
  }
  getApiData(): Observable<any> {
    console.log(this.apiData);
    return this.httpClient.get(this.apiData);
  }
  toggleDiv(): void {
    document.querySelectorAll('div.col-md-3').setAttribute()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is an Angular best practice to avoid directly interfacing with elements in the DOM. Ideally, you should be using [Angular's `Renderer2` service](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to achieve this:

```js
  import {Component, OnInit, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

  ...

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {
  }

  ...

  toggleDiv() {
    const divs: NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement> = document.querySelectorAll('div.col-md-3');
    divs.forEach(div => this.renderer.setAttribute(div, 'attr', 'val'));
  }
```